# PowerShell v3 Invoke-WebRequest: Troubles with forms

Tags: forms, powershell, web, webrequest

Since I upgraded to Windows 8 a lot of my PowerShell scripts relying on launching an invisible IE won’t quite work anymore, so I tried switching to the *Invoke-WebRequest* command. I did a lot of googling but still can’t get my script to work.

This is what it should do:

1. load up a website with a simple form (username, password, submit-button),
2. enter the credentials
3. and submit them.

The [Microsoft tech-net examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) were not very helpful for me, that is what I pieced together:

```
$myUrl = "http://some.url"  

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUrl -Method Default -SessionVariable $rb
$form = $response.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["user"]     = "username"
$form.Fields["password"] = "password"

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $form.Action -WebSession $rb -Method POST 
$response.StatusDescriptionOK
```

I receive two errors, the first one when trying to write into the `user` field:

```
Cannot index into a null array.

$form.Fields["user"]     = "username"

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The second one has to do with the `$form.Action` which I have no idea what it should read:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is  null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command  again.
```

Again, I relied heavily on [example #2 at Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx).

Answer (score 16):

Try doing the post directly e.g.:

```
$formFields = @{username='john doe';password='123'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUrl -Method Post -Body $formFields -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Keith. I just tried it, but I came across some more troubles. First of all, I need to get past a certificate error to even reach the login-form. I did this override manually in a browser for now, yet on the login-page I get for any _Invoke-WebRequest_ the following error: `Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`…

Answer (score 7):

To address your problem with the unsigned/untrusted certificate, add the line

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

before the Invoke-WebRequest statement

Answer (score 3):

The example in the question works, but you have to use `rb` and not `$rb` in the first line:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUrl -Method Default -SessionVariable rb
```

I also had to use `($myUrl + '/login')` since this is my login address.

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($myUrl + '/login') -Method Default -SessionVariable rb

And in the last line used `($myUrl + $form.Action)`:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($myUrl + $form.Action) -WebSession $rb -Method POST
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're me and have been troubleshooting a bad Web Request, in my case a `-Body` that was becoming `null` at my API, then you will want to know about the gotcha that is about interleaving your line continuations with comments.  This

```
$r = iwr -uri $url `
    -method 'POST' `
    -headers $headers `
    # -contenttype 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ` # default
    -Body $body
```

Notice the commented out line `# -contenttype 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' # default`

Putting a comment truncates the remaining back-ticked line continuation.  Therefore, in my case my web request ended up with a request having 0-byte payload.