# Invoke-WebRequest, POST with parameters

Tags: powershell, rest

I'm attempting to POST to a uri, and send the parameter `username=me`

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foobar -Method POST
```

How do I pass the parameters using the method POST?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13732610/1630171) to a similar question.

Comment: You can also consider [this Q/A or the referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13732610/4575793).

Answer (score 387, accepted):

Put your parameters in a hash table and pass them like this:

```
$postParams = @{username='me';moredata='qwerty'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foobar -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

Comment: For my future reference as much as anyone else's info, the hash table can also be passed, one-liner-style, directly to the -Body parameter.

Comment: add $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue' to speed things up by factor of 10.

Comment: I would try this `non-json` `hash-table` solution first before going to the json version, see @rob.

Comment: Just some more content. Thanks to Timo, [link to rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323588/4575793). The oneliner like cori suggested would be `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://example.com/foobar -Method POST -Body @{username='me';moredata='qwerty'}` (possibly with `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`).

Pay attention that in comparison to `curl` you have no quotation marks `"` for the variable names and `=` instead of `:` and `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: `-UseDefaultCredentials` to pass in the Windows authentication user

Answer (score 129):

For some picky web services, the request needs to have the content type set to JSON and the body to be a JSON string. For example:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://example.com/service -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body "{ 'ItemID':3661515, 'Name':'test'}"
```

or the equivalent for XML, etc.

Answer (score 38):

This just works:

```
$body = @{
 "UserSessionId"="12345678"
 "OptionalEmail"="MyEmail@gmail.com"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$header = @{
 "Accept"="application/json"
 "connectapitoken"="97fe6ab5b1a640909551e36a071ce9ed"
 "Content-Type"="application/json"
} 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://MyServer/WSVistaWebClient/RESTService.svc/member/search" -Method 'Post' -Body $body -Headers $header | ConvertTo-HTML
```

Comment: Possibly stupid question, but how do I know the `connectapitoken`? Or is this optional?

Comment: @Cadoiz, it's optional, as other Headers. Depends on the service you are consuming, if it cares about those values.

Comment: I think you forgot ; to separate properties from each other in the object bodies.

Comment: @Barabas, Thank you for your comment. I cannot tell because I cannot test it but when I wrote this, yes, I tested it and it was working like that. So, not sure I'm missing the `;`

Answer (score 19):

**Single command** without ps variables when using `JSON` as body `{lastName:"doe"}` for POST api call:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer N-1234ulmMGhsDsCAEAzmo1tChSsq323sIkk4Zq9"} `
                  -Method POST `
                  -Body (@{"lastName"="doe";}|ConvertTo-Json) `
                  -Uri https://api.dummy.com/getUsers `
                  -ContentType application/json
```

---

See more: [Power up your PowerShell](https://gourav.io/blog/powershell)

Comment: Attention! In comparison to curl you have `=` instead of `:`. You're doing it correct in the code block, but maybe not above. `;` instead of `,` is correct and the quotation marks `"` for the variable names are alright and just not wanted by PowerShell.