# Creating a scheduled task to "ping"/"poke" a URL via a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, wsh

### What I want to do

I want to daily ping/poke a URL to activate a action I have written in C#, and is running on a webserver. To do this I expected that I could use the task scheduler.

### My setup

I have set up the scheduled tasks action to call this program:

```
C:\...\_resources\callurl.cmd"
```

Created from this code taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20787029/1955317)

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem **** batch zone *********************************************************

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Batch file will delegate all the work to the script engine 
    if not "%~1"=="" (
        wscript //E:JScript "%~dpnx0" %1
    )

    rem End of batch area. Ensure batch ends execution before reaching
    rem javascript zone
    exit /b

@end
// **** Javascript zone *****************************************************
// Instantiate the needed component to make url queries
var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0');

// Retrieve the url parameter
var url = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

    // Make the request

    http.open("POST", url, false);
    http.send();

    // All done. Exit
    WScript.Quit(0);
```

I then add the following argument to the task

```
/c "http://localhost/Controller/ActionToInvoke?guid=SOME-GUID"
```

The idea to use "/c" I have from [this question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/44120d29-cb25-4478-999e-f1a4e9dfa304/command-runs-successfully-from-a-cmd-prompt-but-not-when-using-task-scheduler).

The useraccount used to run the task is SYSTEM

When I do this nothing happens. Sometimes i CMD windows pops up for a split second, sometimes nothing happens. In both cases I can't see my action being hit (debugging the application and have set a breakpoint at the entry point)

### Running it in CMD

If I open up my command promt, and run the command like this

```
callurl.cmd "http://localhost/Controller/ActionToInvoke?guid=SOME-GUID"
```

there is no problem. Here callurl.cmd does what I expect it to do, it calls my action.

What can I be doing wrong? Is there something here that I don't see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to do this via Powershell instead. It's way easier and perfectly works with the scheduler. Here is the code to call/trigger a URL:

```
$url="http://localhost/Controller/ActionToInvoke?guid=SOME-GUID"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$url");
```

Save this code in a *.ps1 file and create a task to execute it. That's it. No batch, no Java-/VBScript, etc. Just pure Powershell.

If you didn't allow the execution of ps scripts on your computer yet this is how you do this:

1. Open Powershell as administrator
2. execute the command `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`

There are different viable policies instead of `remotesigned`. I even prefere `unrestricted` instead.

**EDIT:** If you want to be able to pass a URL as parameter, here is the modified code:

```
param([String]$url="")
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$url");
```

Call the file using `filename.ps1 -url http://localhost/Controller/ActionToInvoke?guid=SOME-GUID`.

You can also go to the task scheduler, create a new task, enter all the random stuff, go to "Actions" enter `powershell` into the "Program/script" field and `"C:\MyScript.ps1 -url http://localhost/Controller/ActionToInvoke?guid=SOME-GUID"` into the "Add arguments (optional)" field.

Comment: I need to be able to feed the batch file with a parameter as this file will have to be used A LOT of places, all with different URL's. I donøt see how to do that with your suggestion?

Comment: @Squazz Modified my answer. Now you can pass the URL as a parameter.

Comment: trying to do this, all that happens is notepad opening the file?

Comment: Wait what? What is your file called? Why is notepad opening ps1 files? Is it possible that your file is called something like file.ps1.txt?

Comment: Nope, the filetype is just .ps1, but I can see in the preferences that it is set to be opened with Notepad :/ Never touched any of this, never run powerscript on my conputer before, so don't know why that is

Comment: Do you even have powershell installed? What happens if oyu execute powershell.exe?

Comment: If it is, try to execute this code: `powershell "C:\MyScript.ps1 -url http://www.google.com"` (insert proper path to the script and the URL ^^) This should output the HTML code of the destination URL to the console. Just ignore the output. It just makes sure that your script worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94927/discussion-between-michaels-and-squazz).

Comment: Haha, I was just about to click "submit" to the exactly same edit :P

Comment: Now, I'm not strong in powershell, but isn't this a GET request? Would love to be able to lock it down so only POST requests are accepted by my action. Is there a way to make the script do a POST request?

Comment: Not sure how exactly to do this but this post should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325293/invoke-webrequest-post-with-parameters