# Servicem8 API cURL Post

Tags: curl, servicem8

im having a little issue with cURL post commands

```
curl --user "user:pass" --request POST https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/note.json --data '{"note":"AdvNotice 48 Hours","related_object":"company","related_object_uuid":"b1cca357-5e00-464e-b66c-8546d6b4963b"}'
```

i get the response

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bad Request</h1>
        <p>Bad Request. No data received in POST</p>
        <hr />
        <address>ServiceM8/1</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have fiddled with this for a little and tried posting this data via REST clients, that work fine but just not in cURL,

any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good reason I can think of to want to use it in CMD.

There is however a good reason to want to use it in Windows, without the need for cygwin for instance.

You can do this in PowerShell.

### First of all

**The `-u` option in `cURL` is not portable**.  You should understand it's a `cURL` specific feature where it will try a number of common authentication types.  In this case, it is [basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).  So, for good practise, in your scripts and programs, you should use `-H "Authorization: Basic <base64-Data>`

For instance;

If my username was `myname@domain.com`, and my password was `mypassword`, the format would be like this:

- myname@domain.com:mypassword
- Transform that into base64 is `bXluYW1lQGRvbWFpbi5jb206bXlwYXNzd29yZA==`
- Turn that into an accepted header is:

  ```
  Authorization: Basic bXluYW1lQGRvbWFpbi5jb206bXlwYXNzd29yZA==
  ```
- Turn that into a `cURL` option is:

  ```
  -H "Authorization: Basic bXluYW1lQGRvbWFpbi5jb206bXlwYXNzd29yZA=="
  ```

To make a base64 header, is as simple as typing into your GNU terminal:

```
echo -n 'myname@domain.com:mypassword' | openssl base64 -base64
```

Or by using PowerShell builtins:

```
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("myname@domain.com:mypassword")))
```

### Secondly

You can make a template for this in windows using PowerShell ISE.

For instance, in ServiceM8, this would list all of your clients:

```
$user = 'username@domain.com'
$pass = 'myPassword'
$method = 'GET'
$base64Creds = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(($user+":"+$pass)))
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", 'application/json')
$headers.Add("Authorization", $base64Creds)
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/company.json' -Method $method -Headers $headers
Write-Output $response
```

You can post data by changing the `$method` to POST and adding a content body, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330952/3544399):

> Put your parameters in a hash table and pass them like this:
> `$postParams = @{username='me';moredata='qwerty'} Invoke-WebRequest
> -Uri http://example.com/foobar -Method POST -Body $postParams`

In PowerShell you could access the properties of the output object.  `$response.name`, `$response.billing_address`, `$response.uuid`, etc..

If you absolutely must use CMD, then I'd suggest wrapping up the above into a `ps1` file and executing it from your batch script using `powershell -executionPolicy bypass -file "C:\Users\Whatever\MyCmd.ps1"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, also if you want json result instead of xml, add the header `Accept: application/json` :

```
curl -u "user:password" "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/note.json" \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{
        "note" : "AdvNotice 48 Hours",
        "related_object" : "company",
        "related_object_uuid" : "b1cca357-5e00-464e-b66c-8546d6b4963b"
     }'
```

One liner :

```
curl -u "user:password" "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/note.json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"note\" : \"AdvNotice 48 Hours\", \"related_object\" : \"company\", \"related_object_uuid\" : \"b1cca357-5e00-464e-b66c-8546d6b4963b\" }"
```

Comment: Thanks Mate
I have tried this on windows it does not seem to work with CMD but i did try it in Terminal and it works. 

Is there something i need to change to get this working with CMD?

Comment: You can use `curl -u "user:password" "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/note.json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"note\" : \"AdvNotice 48 Hours\", \"related_object\" : \"company\", \"related_object_uuid\" : \"b1cca357-5e00-464e-b66c-8546d6b4963b\" }"`