# TFS build step - Execute POST web request

Tags: tfs

I need to create a step in our TFS build process that will fire off a POST request using basic auth.

How can I execute a POST web request using a TFS build step? Do I need to run a PowerShell script or is there another way?
I would prefer not using PowerShell if possible due to permission restrictions on our build server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Agentless phase to your build and use the Invoke REST API task.

Comment: Thank you Daniel but I can't find where to add an agentless phase :( I am not using Azure. Our TFS instance is on-prem version 2017.

Comment: It may be called a "Server" phase in 2017

Comment: The Agentless phase not available in TFS 2017. I think you must use PowerShell, do you know how?

Comment: We updated to 2018 Update 3 and the "agentless phase" is now available. @ShaykiAbramczyk you can submit a POST request in PowerShell as described here [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325293/invoke-webrequest-post-with-parameters)