# TFS 2018 - How to receive build started and finished events

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

We are writing plugin for TFS that expects to receive BuildStarted and BuildCompleted Events.

We found that BuildCompletedEvent can be received via WebHooks.

But BuildStartedEvent is not possible to receive via WebHooks .

Does exist any other way to receive BuildStarted event in TFS 2018?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hook for BuildStartedEvent ([Azure DevOps Services service hooks events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops)). 
You may use the workaround:

1. Add as first step inline powershell task ([PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)) and send information about your started build ([Invoke-WebRequest, POST with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325293/invoke-webrequest-post-with-parameters)) to your service.

OR

2. Create .net app to send a web request ([How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)) to your service. Then add first step with command line ([Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)) to run your custom app.