# PowerShell - Slack API - Room History - Post method with x-www-form-urlencoded parameters

Tags: powershell, urlencode, slack-api

I want to pass a few body parameters using x-www-form-urlencoded format using powershell invoke-restmethod. Do not that this is working fine in PostMan. My code for this is below but is not working. How do I accomplish this in powershell?

```
$param = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("channel:channelID
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
limit:50")


$uri="https://MySlackWebsite.com/api/channels.history"

$test2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headerJson -Body $param
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work with the following using the guidance I got from @Erik Kalkoken.

```
$headerJson = @{Authorization="Bearer xoxp-xyz"}
$postParams = @{channel='roomID';limit=50}
$uri="https://slackserver.com/api/channels.history"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headerJson -Body $postParams -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example script on how to retrieve the list of messages from a channel with a POST request.

```
$postParams = @{token='xoxp-XXX';channel='C12345678'}
$test2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://slack.com/api/channels.history -Method POST -Body $postParams
Write-Host $test2
```

It tested and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325293/invoke-webrequest-post-with-parameters) about how to create a POST request with PowerShell.

Comment: Hey Erik, that part works fine. Please note that I have gotten this to work in post man. The issue that I'm having with is in powershell where converting header params to application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not working, causing my invoke rest method requests to fail.

Comment: This example is posting as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Which params exactly are not working for you?

Comment: This is the code that I'm testing with:

<code>
$req = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("channel:ChangelID
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
limit:50")
$uri="https://slackserver.com/api/channels.history"

$test2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headerJson -Body $req -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
<code>

Comment: ok, but why do you not just use the code I posted? It does exactly what you are asking I think