# How create a subtask in jira automatically in case of build failure in Bamboo

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, python-jira

I have an Automation test project in Bamboo, For each build failure, I need to create a subtask in Jira. How I can achieve this goal through automation. Is it possible to write a shell script for this case?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can try different things about that issue:

1. [Post-build action from Bamboo](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/post-build-completed-action-module/)

After the build is done, you can call a custom Post-Build action which calls the Jira Rest API to create the new issue.

2. Creating a Powershell (because of the tag) which calls a POST request

You can directly send a HTTP request from Powershell with `Invoke-WebRequest` command.
You can check out [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325293/invoke-webrequest-post-with-parameters) for the POST request.
And of course, you will send the POST request to the Jira in order to create a sub-task. You can check out [this Jira documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-examples/#creating-a-sub-task) for creating a sub-task through Jira Rest Api.

3. You can [create an Event Listener in Bamboo](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/bamboo-event-listeners/)

Inside the listener, you can connect to Jira and create a sub-task through the Jira Rest Api with a simple HTTP request, similar to the second bullet.

Comment: Thank you  for your input, I have one doubt from the Bamboo listener events, I could not find any event for Build failure. If the build fails what event do I need to use.

Comment: Actually, BuildFinishedEvent should work for you. It listens both successful or failed builds.