# Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LfO'

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to install Airflow with docker on my desktop.

When I run `curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.3/docker-compose.yaml'` like the internet says, I get this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LfO'.
At line:1 char:6
+ curl -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.3/docke ...
+      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

And I can't find any info over the web :(

Answer (score 82):

This question ranks highly on Google for some reason, which means I regularly click through here when I encounter this issue. For the sake of my sanity, and anyone else who arrives here, here's the answer:

Execute this in the command prompt:

```
Remove-item alias:curl
```

**Explanation:** There's a CmdLet called `Invoke-WebRequest` which has an alias of `curl`. So when you execute this command, rather than using `curl`, it tries to use `Invoke-WebRequest`. Removing this alias allows you to execute `curl` as you intended.

Windows Terminal seems to have `Invoke-WebRequest` set up by default, so I occasionally find myself needing to run the `Remove-item`.

Comment: The devil is in the details. Maybe there was good intent behind this but I feel it only adds to chaos.

Comment: wow real magic!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works perfectly but for poeple who don't want to mess with powershell, just run *wsl* (Windows Subsystem for Linux) if you have it and let windows deal with it's own issues. This command would run without error in an Ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using the -k:

```
curl -k -LfO 'https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.7.3/...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation provided by microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest

I solved it by using `-uri` in the parameters:

```
curl -uri http://example.com

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {123, 34, 107, 101...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                    Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https:
                    data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:...
Headers           : {[Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *], [Content-Security-Policy, default-src 'self';base-uri
                    'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self'        
                    data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https:
                    'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests], [Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy, require-corp],
                    [Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy, same-origin]...}
RawContentLength  : 372
```

As you can see the content is in binary format. If you want to see it you have to define an output file:

```
curl -uri http://example.com -outfile response.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with using `Invoke-WebRequest`, just use it like so (assuming you did not `Remove-item alias:curl`):

```
curl -Uri http://<some-address>:<some-port>/ -Method POST -Body @{param1='my param';param2='420'}
```

You can also (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330952/3303532)) do the following:

```
$postParams = @{param1='my param';param2='420'}
curl -Uri http://<some-address>:<some-port>/ -Method POST -Body $postParams
```