# How to send a HTTP Post request using curl?

Tags: curl

I am building a server using rust and I have two endpoints exposed `health_check` and `subscriptions`, the former has a GET request handler and the later has POST request handler

```
pub fn run(listener: TcpListener) -> Result<Server, std::io::Error> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .route("/health_check", web::get().to(health_check))
            .route("/subscriptions", web::post().to(subscribe))
    })
        .listen(listener)?
        .run();
    Ok(server)
}
```

When I run a curl get request at the `health_check` endpoint i get a `200 OK` response as desired but when I run a curl post request at the `subscriptions` endpoint
`curl -d "name=le%20guin&email=ursula_le_guin%40gmail.com" http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscriptions` I get an error

```
Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscriptions'.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -d "name=le%20guin&email=ursula_le_guin%40gmail.com"   http://12 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I think there is something wrong with this command, i checked on google and some articles say to add `-X POST` option in the command but that too doesnt seem to work

Comment: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/08/19/removing-the-powershell-curl-alias/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lfalck/fbb04ef438b521064e0c5742bcd28c2f

Comment: You are using Invoke-Webrequest. Not the real curl :)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM is there a way i can put a post request using Invoke-Webrequest then?

Comment: Yes, You can [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330952/6699447)