# Using Plumber to create an API that generates a report file through an RMD script

Tags: r, post, plumber

I am trying to create an API that receives two xlsx files that are used as parameters for my RMD file that generates a Word file at the end and send it back to my web app.

As for my plumber.R script, it looks like this:

```
#* @post /generate_report
function(req, res) {

  team_file1 <- req$files$fichier1
  team_file2 <- req$files$fichier2
  
  tmp1 <- tempfile(tmpdir = getwd())
  team1 <- readxl::read_excel(team_file1$datapath)
  team2 <- readxl::read_excel(team_file2$datapath)
  
  output_path <- paste0(getwd(), "/rapport_.docx")
  
  rmarkdown::render("rapport_.Rmd", output_file = output_path, output_format = "word_document",
                    params = list(team1 = team1, team2 = team2))
  
  file_content <- readBin(output_path, "raw", n = file.info(output_path)$size)
  
  # à tester encore mais ça devrait renvoyer le doc généré : 
  res$setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
  res$setHeader("Content-Disposition", sprintf("attachment; filename=%s", "rapport_.docx"))
  res$status(200)
  res$body(file_content)
}
```

I run it like this and it works just fine:

```
library(plumber)    
library(rmarkdown)    
r <- plumb("plumber.R")  # Where 'plumber.R' is the location of the file shown above    
r$run(port=8000, swagger = TRUE, host = "0.0.0.0")
```

I wanted to test the generate report function from my terminal using this command :

`curl -X POST -F "fichier1=@fichier1.xlsx" -F "fichier2=@fichier2.xlsx" http://127.0.0.1:8000/generate_report -o rapport_.docx`

I get this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Impossible de trouver un paramètre correspondant au nom « X ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 6
+ curl -X POST -F "fichier1=@fichier1.xlsx" -F "fichier2=@fichier2.xlsx ...
+      ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Any idea as to why?

Comment: If you are using windows powershell, note that `curl` is just a wrapper to `Invoke-WebRequest` see https://www.educative.io/answers/curl-in-powershell See how to send a post request in powershell here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325293/invoke-webrequest-post-with-parameters