# Trying to use getElementById in Powershell with IE 11, error Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-11, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to automate logging in on a website, but I can't seem to use getElementById. getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0] seems to work, but the elements I need don't have class names and I can't change that.

I'm using PS 5, IE 11. Here's an example of my code, and the resulting exception.

```
$url = "https://google.com"
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)
while ($ie.Busy){Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000}
$ie.document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "test"
```

Error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At C:\gtest.ps1:6 char:1
+ $ie.document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "test"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException
```

Comment: why not https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks, trying that now. Can't figure out how to submit it after setting the form fields though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logging into google

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest "https://google.bg" -SessionVariable g

$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://accounts.google.bg/' -WebSession $g

$r.Forms['gaia_loginform'].Fields.Email = 'someuser@gmail.com'
$r.Forms['gaia_loginform'].Fields.Passwd = 'somepass'

$r = Invoke-RestMethod $r.Forms['gaia_loginform'].Action -Body $r.Forms['gaia_loginform'] -Method $r.Forms['gaia_loginform'].Method  -WebSession $g

$r = Invoke-WebRequest https://google.bg -WebSession $g

$r.Content > tmp2.html
```

hope that helps

Comment: Getting an error: Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again. $r = Invoke-RestMethod $r.Forms[0].Action -Body $r.Forms[0] Method $ ...

Comment: it should be working. are you trying it on google? if not check your form for its 'action' -- if its a "full" url, not relative etc

Comment: It works on Google but not on where I actually need it to. I'm using Fiddler Web Debugger to look at the HTTP requests to maybe see what I'm missing, but I don't understand much of this. Trying to login to a printer. `POST http://PrinterIP/login.html?/main.html HTTP/1.1
Host: PrinterIP
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://printerIP
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

ggt_select%2810009%29=3&ggt_textbox%2810003%29=admin&action=loginbtn&ordinate=0&ggt_hidden%2810008%29=5`

Comment: idk, I would try "manually" constructing the headers and the body and using just the sessin variable to keep track of any coockies... NOT using '-Body $r.Forms['gaia_loginform']' but putting together the string 'ggt_select%2810009%29=3&ggt_textbox%2810003%29=admin&action=loginbtn&ordinate=0&‌​ggt_hidden%2810008%29=5' myself and such

Comment: PS But yeah, Fiddler is the tool and id try matching what I see there

Comment: this looks similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729434/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-troubles-with-forms

Comment: Hey, using the string for the body actually works! Is there any way to avoid doing that though? Other processes in the same system I'm looking to automate have huuuge body strings (over 6k characters).

Comment: One better way I can think of is to loop through each form.field and construct a string that way, but I'm having trouble looping through all the fields. I tried `foreach ($field in $r.Forms[0].Fields)` but I can't seem to do something like `$b = $b+$field.Key+'='+field.Value+'&'` - I don't think Forms[0].Fields is an array...

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$ie.Document.documentElement.getElementByClassName();
$ie.Document.documentElement.getElementByTagName();
$ie.Document.documentElement.getAttribute();
```

and for id name tagname use this

```
$ie.Document.IHTML3_getElementById();
$ie.Document.IHTML3_getElementByName();
$ie.Document.IHTML3_getElementByTagName();
```

Comment: @Alberto sometimes when page is loaded correctly or else, we dont have access to `documentElment` so `IHTML3..` does the same